# Thread.sleep(1500) works where driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS) does not

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

Many of the dropdowns on the webpage I'm working has the selections populated dynamically. When working with Selenium sometimes I need a wait moving from one element to the other.

I tried using `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS)` but it doesn't seem to be working as I'd expect and often the elements still aren't found. I thought I'd try using `Thread.sleep(1500)` and it works every time. Does anyone have any idea why this is? I would think the wait would be the better of the two?

Comment: post your code trials and exceptions thrown.  Basically implicit will only wait until an element is found, but that is not necessarily all you need to wait for.

Comment: It was my understanding it would simply wait the number is TimeUnits I specify, in this case 2 seconds. Is that not correct?

Comment: it'll wait until the element is found, which could be sooner.  It will only work on findElement or findElements I believe...  it polls the DOM every 1/2 second.

Comment: Never use Thread. Use Pyppeteer if you must have concurrency.